# how to get json using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, json

json data example

```
{
  "CPU Running": {
    "user": "Yama/Rayno",
    "container": [
      "C-23-1",
      "C-24-1",
      "C-40-1"
    ]
  },
  "Nonstop CPU": {
    "user": "Kang/Yoon",
    "container": [
      "C-25-1",
      "C-26-1",
      "C-31-1",
      "C-32-1",
      "C-33-1",
      "C-34-1",
      "C-37-1",
      "C-38-1"
    ]
  }
```

i use this script
but change `${data[i].job}` row

```js
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  if (data[i].container != null) {
    var add_data = `<tr>
      <td>
        ${data[i].container}
      </td>
      <td>
        ${data[i].user}
      </td>
      <td>
        ${data[i].job}
      </td>
    </tr>`;
```

how to output this format?
CPU Running, Nonstop CPU as Job name
what calling this space in json?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you json data is incomplete. An additional `}` should be added at the end of your data.

I am not writing a full solution, rather showing how you can access your data.
Getting `CPU Running` data, This is an object, containing another two fields: user and an list-container.
So access the `CPU-Running` event like this:

```
var cpuRunner= yourJsonData["CPU Running"]; //assuming `yourJsonData` holds your json data
var cpuRunnerUser= cpuRunner["user"];
var containerList= cpuRunner["container"]; //this is your container list for cpu-running
```

Now, iterate on this containerList for your  html for cpuRunning containers
Similarly,
you can get the container list for `Nonstop CPU` too

Answer (score 0):

inside of html page select place for your table, and add table style to css or just put in the html page header

```
 <p id="showData"></p>
```

and this is a javascript code

```
function CreateTableFromJSON(obj) {

  // CREATE DYNAMIC TABLE.
  var table = document.createElement("table");

  // ADD JSON DATA TO THE TABLE AS ROWS.
  iterateData(obj, table);

  // FINALLY ADD THE NEWLY CREATED TABLE WITH JSON DATA TO A CONTAINER.
  var divContainer = document.getElementById("showData");
  divContainer.innerHTML = "";
  divContainer.appendChild(table);
}

function iterateData(obj, table) {

  Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
    if (typeof obj[key] === "object") {
      var tr = table.insertRow(-1);
      var tabCell1 = tr.insertCell(-1);

      if (key == "container") tabCell1.innerHTML = key;
      else {
        tabCell1.innerHTML = "Job";
        var tabCell2 = tr.insertCell(-1);
        tabCell2.innerHTML = key;
      }
      iterateData(obj[key], table);
    }

    tr = table.insertRow(-1);
    if (key == "user") {
      var tabCell1 = tr.insertCell(-1);
      tabCell1.innerHTML = key;
    }
    if (typeof obj[key] == "string") {
      var tabCell2 = tr.insertCell(-1);
      tabCell2.innerHTML = obj[key];
    }
  });
}
```